# ARKit template Xcode project Main Thread Checker log console

Tags: ios

I just started a new Xcode ARKit project and ran it on a physical device but in the console I'm getting this output:

```
Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIApplication applicationState]
PID: 4865, TID: 2042694, Thread name: com.apple.CoreMotion.MotionThread, Queue name: com.apple.root.default-qos.overcommit, QoS: 0
Backtrace:
4   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001d7477894 <redacted> + 56
5   CoreMotion                          0x00000001ddcf4760 CoreMotion + 304992
6   CoreMotion                          0x00000001ddcf4c94 CoreMotion + 306324
7   CoreMotion                          0x00000001ddcf4ba4 CoreMotion + 306084
8   CoreMotion                          0x00000001ddd26384 CoreMotion + 508804
9   CoreMotion                          0x00000001ddd263e4 CoreMotion + 508900
10  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001d820d4d8 <redacted> + 28
11  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001d820cdbc <redacted> + 276
12  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001d82080c0 <redacted> + 2324
13  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001d8207494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
14  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001d82081f8 CFRunLoopRun + 84
15  CoreMotion                          0x00000001ddd25d1c CoreMotion + 507164
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001d7e829c8 <redacted> + 132
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001d7e82924 _pthread_start + 52
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001d7e8addc thread_start + 4
2018-11-19 09:21:42.623520-0800 MyFirstARKitApp[4865:2042694] [reports] Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIApplication applicationState]
PID: 4865, TID: 2042694, Thread name: com.apple.CoreMotion.MotionThread, Queue name: com.apple.root.default-qos.overcommit, QoS: 0
Backtrace:
4   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001d7477894 <redacted> + 56
5   CoreMotion                          0x00000001ddcf4760 CoreMotion + 304992
6   CoreMotion                          0x00000001ddcf4c94 CoreMotion + 306324
7   CoreMotion                          0x00000001ddcf4ba4 CoreMotion + 306084
8   CoreMotion                          0x00000001ddd26384 CoreMotion + 508804
9   CoreMotion                          0x00000001ddd263e4 CoreMotion + 508900
10  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001d820d4d8 <redacted> + 28
11  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001d820cdbc <redacted> + 276
12  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001d82080c0 <redacted> + 2324
13  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001d8207494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
14  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001d82081f8 CFRunLoopRun + 84
15  CoreMotion                          0x00000001ddd25d1c CoreMotion + 507164
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001d7e829c8 <redacted> + 132
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001d7e82924 _pthread_start + 52
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001d7e8addc thread_start + 4
```

My question to you guys is why I'm getting this output? and what it means ?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: It means precisely what it says: something is calling `-[UIApplication applicationState]` on a background thread.

Comment: @Gereon, how can I fix this ?

Comment: Identify the offending code and run it on the main thread instead. However, this might be a bug in iOS 12, as it looks very similar to other reports, like https://github.com/lionheart/openradar-mirror/issues/20515. If that's the case, file a bugreport with apple.

Comment: This is a bug and there is currently no known solution.

Answer (score 2):

(Of course you can disable checker, but sometimes it can be helpful. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/45689250/7183675 for this.)

Error is inside Apple framework, so only way I found do work around it was subclassing UIApplication class and check application state on main thread this way:

1) Add main.swift file (this name is really important!) with these lines

```
import UIKit

    UIApplicationMain(
        CommandLine.argc,
        CommandLine.unsafeArgv,
        NSStringFromClass(MyApplicationClass.self),
        NSStringFromClass(MyDelegateClass.self)
    )
```

2) Remove `@UIApplicationMain` from `MyDelegateClass` if it was there or project wont compile because of multiple entry points

3) In MyApplicationClass.swift add this:

```
    import UIKit

    class MyApplicationClass: UIApplication {
    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
    override var applicationState: UIApplication.State {
        if Thread.current == Thread.main {
            return super.applicationState
        }

        var toReturn =  UIApplication.State.inactive

        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else {return}
            toReturn = self.superAppState()
            self.semaphore.signal()
        }
        semaphore.wait()
        return toReturn
    }

    private func superAppState() -> UIApplication.State {
        return super.applicationState
    }
}
```

Now you are calling UIApplication.applicationState on main thread, so issue won't occur.

Well, there is one more issue. If CMMotionManager is initialized from main thread then if will block main thread and wait for UIApplication.State. That means deadlock. In this case you can't set your semaphore. Only way to return credible state avoiding deadlock would be implementing application state this way:

4)

```
import UIKit

        class MyApplicationClass: UIApplication {

    private static var configured = false

    private var state = UIApplication.State.inactive

    override var applicationState: UIApplication.State {
        if !MyApplicationClass.configured {
            MyApplicationClass.configured = true
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(setStatus(_:)), name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(setStatus(_:)), name: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification, object: nil)
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(setStatus(_:)), name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(setStatus(_:)), name: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)
        }
        if Thread.current == Thread.main {
            return super.applicationState
        }
        return state
    }

    @objc func setStatus(_ notif: Notification) {
        switch notif.name {
        case UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification:
            state = .active
        case UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification:
            state = .inactive
        case UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification:
            state = .background
        case UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification:
            state = .background
        default:
            state = .inactive
        }
    }
}
```

Personally I don't like last solution, but I wasn't able to find another workaround

Comment: This resolved my issue in iOS 12. The main thread checker was running into this every time I spun up a new instance of ARKit. Since Apple has yet to fix it in iOS 12,  adding this `UIApplication` subclass works for now. Thanks!